# Restrict access to admin

Tags: admin

Iuse this code for restrict access to wordpress admin. But now i must allow access to author too. Only for this roles. Is possible with this code? Really thanks

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
 if ( is_admin() && !current_user_can( 'author' ) && !( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
 wp_redirect( home_url() );exit;
 }
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you are using the role in a check meant for capabilities. The codex specifically says not to do this. Change 'author' to 'publish_posts' before continuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following plugin can help you better and quick :

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want do it without plugin if possible.

Comment: I check this plugin and don't work with i want

Comment: As far as I know , plugin allows all type of restriction setup.

Comment: But i want that user can't go to admin page. Not change capatibilities. And this plugin don´t work with this. This code work, but only with one role. I need use this with two roles.